# How do you change the code page (configure) an IBM 4610-TF6

Tags: printing, thermal-printer

I'm trying to print Arabic font on an IBM 4610-TF6 receipt printer. It's currently connected to a windows laptop via USB. I believe I require some sort of diagnostic or configuration utility that works with the printer, however the IBM website / documentation is just a maze of dead ends so far.

Anyone have any experience doing anything similar?

Comment: Have you managed to print Latin characters on the thermal printer? Are you writing a software or using an existing solution?

Comment: Yes, latin characters print out just fine. This print out is being generated from a piece of self-written software (sends hex comands via com port). The solution works fine for epson model printers and appears to work just fine for IBM in terms of communication, its just the code page thats wrong.

Comment: What is the communication protocol, and does it state something about character tables?

Comment: It's incredibly hard to find solid information on this printer. The closest I've found is http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=AN&subtype=CA&htmlfid=649/ENUSA00-1330#TOC1 

It definitely states that code tables (and alternate fonts) are available, but it doesn't specify how. I'm unaware of what the official communication protocol is.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=pos1R1005015). It seems that IBM had fixed this issue.

Basically what they are telling you is that you have to update OPOS.

It contains pdf file with detailed description. If it doesn't help you try contacting the IBM support.